# Djongo Using ArrayField throws Apps No Loaded Error on makemigrations

Tags: django, django-models, djongo

I am trying to create a django model using djongo which uses ArrayField

```py
class SubModel(models.Model):
    i = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class BiggerModel(models.Model):

    subarr = models.ArrayField(model_container=SubModel)
```

When I run makemigrations, I get the error

> AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")

This is happening only if I use ArrayField. Not with any other fields

I am using `django 2.1.5` and `djongo 1.3.2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug on Djongo 1.3.2. You can downgrade it to 1.3.1 or wait for a new release (until today, 23/Apr, there was a PR merged, but not a new release)

Comment: What versions of Django and pymongo are you using (along with Djongo 1.3.1)?